# Trying to use the Spool Command but no output file

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper, spool

I am trying to run a simple script just to see what might be the problem is. Seems like the spool command doesn't work and it doesn't create an output file though the select statement itself has no error.

Here's what I do. Saved a script in my c: drive, say testscript.sql.

testscript.sql contains:

```
    spool C:\try.txt
    select sysdate from dual;
    spool off;
```

then I ran in SQL Developer:

```
    @ C:\testscript.sql;
```

It does shows the output in the Script Output screen, but upon checking, there's no output file created. I am using a Version 1.1.0.23 Oracle SQL Developer. I am not so sure but is it possible that the spool command doesn't work in this version since there are already much more updated versions of Oracle SQL Developer?

Thanks in advance for help!

Answer (score 1):

Try to run the below command from you worksheet,

```
@\testscript.sql;
```

Comment: Apologies, it should have been @c:\testscript.sql. It did run, showing the date today. But there's no output file. Does the spool command do runs expectedly in a Version 1.1.0 of SQL Developer?

Comment: Yeah, You are right, I tried with SQL Developer v1.1.0, it's executing the result but not getting any output file.